# Free virtualization tool for testing suspicious files

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, virtualization

From time-to-time I test files that are possible infected from any malware. Though sometimes these are false-positives, but at times I need to extract infected archive. Sometimes I don't have another PC and want to try this risky thing on my main PC.

Firstly, how can Virtualization help in this scenario? Secondly, is there any free and reliable Virtualization tool for Windows 7?

Comment: Several posts have suggested MS Virtual PC. One advantage to this over other solutions is that you are free to use a virtualized installation of Windows XP (via XP Mode) on any computer with Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate. If you use something like Virtual Box, you may have to purchase a Windows license to use in the virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like others mention, you can use **virtualization** like [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to keep your specimens quarantined inside.
Problem is, it's kind of **like building an isolation ward** in your kid's room: it's safe and there's no chance of escape (or at least abysmal), but on the other hand it's hard to install/maintain another system (virtual or not) and your computer may occasionally whine about resource usage if you don't have 12GB of RAM in your system.

The other option is **sandboxing**. If virtualization is an isolation ward, then sandboxing **is a playroom**.
It's far easier to set up and maintain (and less mentally disturbing :-) and also has less resource usage (it's just another room), won't whine about resource usage, and lets you have the same comforts of your regular system.
Solutions like [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) (shareware, $40) and [Acronis True Image's "Try&Decide" feature](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) (commercial, $30) or even the almost-dead [Steadystate](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=d077a52d-93e9-4b02-bd95-9d770ccdb431&displaylang=en) (free) under a Guest account (well, if you were running XP or Vista still) are all valid sandboxers.

The third option is to just send it to a **virus analyzer** like [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/) or [Jotti](http://virusscan.jotti.org/en). If your file is less than 20MB, they will open up the archive (IIRC MSI, ZIP, TGZ, and a few others) and then scan the thing using **over 9000 virus scanning engines** and report back with the results.

You mentioned self-extracting archives. Something like [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) might help you by **extracting the files from the archive without running the installer** itself. Then you can run your normal antivirus or use VirusTotal for the individual files in the archive.

Answer (score 3):

Try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution that doesn't use virtualization is either [Returnil](http://www.returnilvirtualsystem.com/) or [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/).

Both allow one to run software without letting it modify the operating system.
However, all changes that the program virtually effects are lost after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few free choices for virtualization [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and [virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) among others.

Both (all VM software?) allows you to save a state of the virtual computer. You can then test your suspicious files and then revert the virtual computer to the way it was before your test.

Answer (score 2):

One way virtualization might help is by copying a template VM, testing the files in the copied instamce of the template VM - presumably any infection will be of the guest OS in the VM and not of the host OS. Finally delete the VM but keep the clean template.

There are many choices for virtualization software such as several basic VMware products. Since Windows 7 includes virtualisation I know of no good reason not to use that.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way by far is to use Sandboxie. It is free for personal use, however after a certain amount of time or number of uses you will just get a small screen telling you that while free you have to wait a few seconds for it to start running whatever application you want in sandboxed mode. There is a great tutorial here at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5219/run-apps-in-sandboxie-to-keep-your-system-secure/) that explains how to install and set up Sandboxie and also includes a link to download the program. I use Sandboxie all the time to test files of a suspicious nature.

Comment: Sandboxie has already been mentioned by @harrymc. -1

Comment: Oh You've got to be friggin kidding me...what difference does it make if someone else has already mentioned something or not? I don't see where either of the other two users who ALSO mentioned Virtual Box or Sandboxie that had already been mentioned by digitxp in the second post have been punished. What, have you got a hard on for me or something? You edit my posts because I try to be polite and say "Thank You" and now you take whatever these points are away because I offer my opinion on a piece of software and clarify its licensing setup? Sounds kinds personal to me.